# Pie Chart Legend Label Vertical Alignment

Tags: java, android, anychart

We have android mobile application. And it has screen which has pie charts.

We can't align legend labels vertically like as below image.

https://github.com/reactchartjs/react-chartjs-2/issues/348

Legend labels shows without alignment like as above pie chart example image.

How can we align this legends labels like as below pie chart example:

https://billobrien.wordpress.com/2014/04/17/pie-chart-horror/

Thanks for your advice.

Comment: Hello, welcome to Stack Overflow! Maybe you should [read this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557), and then edit your question.